# TFS build definition is giving error after moved from tfs 2010 to tfs 2013

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

## MSDeploy WebApplication

SetParameters from:
"E:\Builds\3\XXX\XX Integration\Binaries_PublishedWebsites\XXX_Package\XXX.SetParameters.xml"
You can change IIS Application Name, Physical path, connectionString

### or other deploy parameters in the above file.

### Start executing msdeploy.exe

"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe" -source:package='E:\Builds\3\XXX\XX Integration\Binaries_PublishedWebsites\XXX_Package\XXX.zip' -dest:auto,computerName='server-name',includeAcls='False' -verb:sync -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -setParamFile:"E:\Builds\3\XXX\XX Integration\Binaries_PublishedWebsites\XXX_Package\XXX.SetParameters.xml"

Error: Remote agent (URL http://server-name/MSDEPLOYAGENTSERVICE) could not be contacted.  Make sure the remote agent service is installed and started on the target computer.
 Error: An unsupported response was received. The response header 'MSDeploy.Response' was '' but 'v1' was expected.
 Error: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
 Error count: 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give permission to the target server for the account that the build agent is running under!

http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/configure-the-web-deployment-handler